# Как перемножить две матрицы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, математика, матрицы

Не срабатывает код умножения матриц,через косноль лог установил что начинает работать до return C; в консоль увы он не выводит ответ.В чем может быть загвоздка?

p.s
видел парочку библиотек с для работы с математическими функциями,подскажите что проще и понятнее,данный вариант или библиотеки к примеру [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html)

```js
  



$(function() {

  //пользоват.фу-ция
  function placeHold() {
matrix.find('tr').each(function(i, v) { //loop each row
  $(v).find('td').each(function(x, d) { //loop each colon in that row
    $(d).find('input').attr('placeholder', matrixID.split('_')[1] + (i + 1) + ',' + (x + 1));
  })
})
  };


  // начальные значения
  var matrixID = $('input[name=mtrx_sel]:checked').val();
  var matrix = $('.' + matrixID);

  $('input[name=mtrx_sel]').on('change', function() {
matrixID = $(this).val();
matrix = $('.' + matrixID);
checkAddStr();
checkAddCol();
checkDelStr();
checkDelCol();
  });


  //обработка кнопок добавить
  $('.add_str').click(function() {
matrix.find('tr:first').clone().appendTo(matrix);
placeHold();
checkAddStr();
checkDelStr(); 
  });

  $('.add_col').click(function() {
matrix.find('tr td:last').clone().appendTo(matrix.find('tr'));
placeHold();
checkAddCol();
checkDelCol(); 
  });


  //проверка активности кнопки доб.стр.
  function checkAddStr() {
if ($("input[value=" + matrixID + "]").prop("checked")) {
  if (matrix.find('tr').length >= 10) {
    $('.add_str').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.add_str').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
  }
  

  //доб.колон.
  function checkAddCol() {
if ($("input[value=" + matrixID + "]").prop("checked")) {
  if (matrix.find('tr:first td').length >= 10) {
    $('.add_col').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.add_col').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
  }
  
  
  function checkDelStr() {
if ($("input[value=" + matrixID + "]").prop("checked")) {
  if (matrix.find('tr').length <= 2) {
    $('.del_str').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.del_str').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
  }
  
 function checkDelCol() {
if ($("input[value=" + matrixID + "]").prop("checked")) {
  if (matrix.find('tr:first td').length <= 2) {
    $('.del_col').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.del_col').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
  }


 
   $(document).on('click', '.del_str', function() {
 matrix.find('tr:last').remove(); 
checkDelStr();
   });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.del_col', function() {
matrix.find('tr td:last-child').remove(); 
checkDelCol(); 
   });

  
  

});

 
 
function readMatrixFromDom(aClassName) {
  var result = [];
  var rows = $('.' + aClassName).find('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    result.push([]);
    var cells = $(rows[i]).find('td > input');
    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
      result[i].push(+$(cells[j]).val());
    }
  }
  return result;
}

  function MultiplyMatrix(A,B){

var A = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_a');
var B = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_b');
var rowsA = A.length, colsA = A[0].length,
    rowsB = B.length, colsB = B[0].length,
    C = [];
if (colsA != rowsB) return false;
for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++) C[i] = [];
for (var k = 0; k < colsB; k++){
  for (var i = 0; i < rowsA; i++){
    var t = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < rowsB; j++) t += A[i][j]*B[j][k];
     C[i][k] = t;
  }
  console.log('check code')
}
   
return C;
          console.log(C);
}
$(document).on('click', '.umn' , function () {
           MultiplyMatrix();
           });
```

```css
.matrix_a_cover {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.matrix_b_cover {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-side">
   <button class="umn">Умножить матрицы</button>
   <br>
   <button class="clear-mtrx btn-style"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i> Очистить матрицы</button>
   <button class="change-mtrx btn-style"><i class="fa fa-exchange" aria-hidden="true"></i>Поменять матрицы местами</button>
   <div class="add_mtrx">
     <span class="rad btn_a">
       <label for="matrix_a">
         <input checked="checked" name="mtrx_sel" type="radio" value="matrix_a" id="check_mtrx_a">Матрица А  
       </label>
     </span>
     <span class="rad btn_b">
       <label for="matrix_b">
         <input type="radio" name="mtrx_sel" value="matrix_b" id="check_mtrx_b">Матрица В
       </label>
     </span>
     <br>
     <div class="add_del_btns">   
       <button class="add_str btn-style" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Добавить</button>
       <button class="del_str btn-style" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Удалить</button> строку
       <br>
       <button class="add_col btn-style" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Добавить</button>
       <button class="del_col btn-style" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Удалить</button> столбец
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main_cover">
   
   <div class="matrix_c_cover">  
      <table class="matrix_c brackets">
        
         <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,1">
           </td>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,2">
           </td> 
            <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c1,3">
           </td>
         </tr> 

         <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,1">
           </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
               <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,2">
            </td>
             <td class="str_inp">
               <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c2,3">
            </td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,1">
           </td>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,2">
           </td>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c3,3">
           </td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c4,1">
           </td>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c4,2">
           </td>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text" disabled placeholder="c4,3">
           </td>
         </tr>

      </table>
   </div>

  <div class="matrix_a_cover">
   <table class="matrix_a brackets" id="matrix_a">
         
          <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a1,1">
           </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a1,2">
           </td>
         </tr>
          
          <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a2,1">
           </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a2,2">
            </td>
         </tr> 
          
        <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a3,1">
           </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a3,2">
          </td>
         </tr>  
          
        <tr>
           <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a4,1">
           </td>
          <td class="str_inp">
             <input type="text"  placeholder="a4,2">
          </td>
         </tr>
       
       
       </table>
   </div>
   
      <div class="matrix_b_cover">
        <table class="matrix_b brackets" id="matrix_b">

           <tr>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,1">
            </td>
             <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,2">
             </td>
             <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,3">
             </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,1">
            </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,2">
            </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,3">
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div> 
      
  </div>
```

Comment: переменные с именами из букв разных регистров - разные переменные

Comment: почему вы удалили столько кода, делающего ваш пример рабочим?

Comment: @Grundy Людям нужно было меньше кода.Я удалил только тот код который не относился к перемножению матриц не более.

Comment: после вашего редактирования - данный ответ потерял актуальность

Comment: @Grundy ну надеюсь данное редактирование не усугубило ситуацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function readMatrixFromDom(aClassName) {
  var result = [];
  var rows = $('.' + aClassName).find('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    result.push([]);
    var cells = $(rows[i]).find('td > input');
    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
      result[i].push(+$(cells[j]).val());
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var A = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_a');
var B = readMatrixFromDom('matrix_b');
```

вместо

```
var A = function(){ 
            $('.matrix_a').find('input');
          };
var b = function(){ 
            $('.matrix_b').find('input');
          };
```

После Ваших присвоений выше, переменные `A` и `b` - это функции, свойство `length` у которых показывает количество ожидаемых параметров (то есть для Вашего кода - 0). Научитесь трассировать код в дебаггере, следить за значениями переменных и читать сообщения об ошибках в консоли.

Возвращение двумерного массива из клик-обработчика - бессмысленно. Код, из которого этот обработчик вызывается, понятия не имеет, что с этим результатом делать. Вы должны сами разложить числа из `C[][]` по инпут-элементам.

**Update**

> начинает работать до return C; в консоль увы он не выводит ответ

Ваш измененный код:

```
  ...
  return C;
  console.log(C);
}
```

Команда `return` означает выход из функции. Код функции после этой команды не выполняется. Поменяйте строки местами и `C` будет выведена в консоль:

```
  ...
  console.log(C);
  return C;
}
```

Comment: Да спасибо,я кок раз не понимал почему есть пустые переменные а и б. Если я правильно понял то переменная result это результат умножения?

Comment: @Drop - Нет, в функции `readMatrixFromDom` переменная `result` это двумерный массив (матрица) считаная со страницы.

Comment: Получается данная функция только ищет и заберает данные из инпутов? а затем уже нужно использовать функцию которая делает расчет и произведение уходит в переменную с массивом c?

Comment: В любом случае как я понимаю нужна эта вся обработка только при нажатии на кнопку т.е все функции будут в функции клика на кнопку. а затем уже идет функция определения инпутов (кстати сделал проще.Вместо aClassName вызвал функцию с определением класса матрицы через выбранный чек бокс) ну затем идет функция расчетов а затем нужна функция вывода?

Comment: _функции, у которых, если мне не изменяет память, вообще нет свойства length_ - изменяет, свойство [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) показывает количество параметров ожидаемых функцией

Comment: @Grundy - Спасибо, это, конечно, не то свойство, которое нужно по смыслу данной задачи.

Comment: Этот комментарий был конкретно к ответу :) В вопросе слишком много лишнего кода, поэтому не смотрел его весь.

Comment: @Igor В консоль все равно не чего не выводиться.Может он не может найти матрицы? как работает переменная rows?

Comment: @igor а нет,перекрестно считывает данные и переносит в массив.Но вот функция умножения не работает.

Comment: @Igor все все,извиняюсь за свою тупость.Все прекрасно выводиться в консоль!